# How do I get a centered equation when I use \documentclass[fleqn]{article}?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Notice I want my equation to have numbering.

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX (and `amsmath` package) do not support this as it is a rather strange request, the style of equations should almost always be a document-wide choice.

That said, if you *really* need this you can make use of the fact that `$$` is not supported latex syntax and does not obey the `fleqn` option.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

zzz
\begin{equation}
  aaa=bbb
\end{equation}
zzz
$$\refstepcounter{equation}
  aaa=bbb
\eqno(\theequation)
$$
zzz
\begin{equation}
  aaa=bbb
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use `\ifvmode \nointerlineskip \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}\fi $$` instead of just $$ to start the display.

Comment: @Skillmon no need for the test, it is not in vmode (and should never be) latex has that test to catch user errors

Answer (score 6):

The `nccmath` package, which defines a `fleqn` environment to be used when  you want to have only some equations aligned at the left margin, has, conversely, a `ceqn` when you want to have occasionally  centred equations in a document with the `fleqn` option. These environments work like (and are compatible with) the `subequations` environment – and all amsmath environments.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{equation}
  aaa=bbb
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{ceqn}
\begin{align}
  aaa & =bbb \\
aaa + c & =bbb + d
\end{align}
\end{ceqn}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]