# latex centering numbered equations

Tags: equations, numbering

I have the following code. Why are my equations not centered, and how can I center them?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{anysize,graphicx,cite,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{authblk}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\marginsize{2.0cm}{2.0cm}{2.0cm}{2.0cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\title{\Large \bf title}
\date{}
\author[1,*]{{author 1}}
\author[1]{author 2}
\affil[1]{\normalsize affiliation
\\ *Email: blank}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\noindent\textit{Keywords:Title}

\bigskip
\noindent\textbf{Abstract}\\

text text text

\section{Introduction}


\begin{align}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} &= \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}\\
                              &= 0
\end{align} 

%Equations with no numbering in specific line by using \nonumber
\begin{align}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} &= \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}\nonumber\\
                              &= 0
\end{align}



$$A(\rho,T) = A_0(\rho)+A_i(\rho,T)+A_e(\rho,T)$$


\section{Methodology}

\section{Results and Discussion}

\section{Conclusion}

\section{Acknowledgments}


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{library}



\end{document}
```

Comment: perhaps you have specified left alignment?we can not guess from the code shown, please show make the example a _complete_ small document that shows the problem.

Comment: This is the output I get (after adding a frame and inserting some reference X's): [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7RWF.png). The equations are centered. If you don't get this type of output, can you supply the community with a minimal document that replicates your issue? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I posted the whole thing

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How do I get a centered equation when I use `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446481/5764)

Comment: so my initial guess was correct:-) you had specified left alignment on code not shown...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My sincere compliments. I didn't imagine that he had inserted the fleqn option. He inserted reqno or removed it and had the alignment of the formulas on the right. Voted your comment positively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `fleqn` option when loading the `\documentclass`.

[image]